# Does 'trip' only mean 'the travelling' or does it include 'the tour'?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm still confused after reading the dictionary explanation. I think the word 'trip' normally emphasise 'the way from A to B', but does it include or mean 'a tour' as well?

For example, “I won a trip to Paris.” Does that mean I won a one-way ticket to Paris, or a round trip ticket, or a round trip ticket plus the sightseeing tickets etc.?

In other words, is there any chance that 'trip' means 'a tour'?

Comment: It would be a god idea to say which dictionary or dictionaries you looked up "trip". I'm pretty sure that most explain what the term means and how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> trip

could mean any of the three

> one-way
>   round trip
>   including a tour

additional context is needed to be explicitly clear.

> I'm taking a trip to Paris and not coming back. *(one way)*
>   I'm taking a trip to Paris for the weekend. *(round trip)*
>   I'm taking a trip to Paris to see the Musee d'Orsay. *(includes a tour of the museum)*

Usually, a "trip" is a "round trip" since it's generally assumed people like where they currently are.

Answer (score 1):

The [Collins Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trip) defines trip as:

> - any tour, journey, or voyage

Comment: There are better and more comprehensive definitions...

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I normally use Collins and the Free dictionary, I don't think it's very clear so I asked this to make sure.